# How to insert csv file into HBase database with help of Phoenix command line tools?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

```
Here is an example:example.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
QUESTION_NO BIGINT NOT NULL,
TECHNOLOGY VARCHAR(40),
SESSION VARCHAR(40),
QUESTION VARCHAR(5000),
OPTION_A VARCHAR(400),OPTION_B VARCHAR(400),
OPTION_C VARCHAR(400),OPTION_D VARCHAR(400),
ANSWER VARCHAR(5)
CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (QUESTION_NO)
);
```

and my csv file contains:example.csv

1, C LANGAUAGE, VARIABLE, Who is the founder of C?, Larry page, Dennis Retchie, Douglas 
   Cutting, Ken Thompson, A

2, C LANGAUAGE, VARIABLE, What are the types of linkages?,Internal and
   External,External,Internal and None,External and None,B

Comment: I tried sqlline commands using (https://bighadoop.wordpress.com/category/hadoop/) but am getting error: csv columns from database.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one column must be provided for upserts

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Phoenix Bulk CSV Data Loading](https://phoenix.apache.org/bulk_dataload.html). It has two options:

- Loading via psql.py/PhoenixRuntime which is fine for small files;
- Loading via MapReduce, which supports bigger data, but currently does not support migration of index data.